# how to get hostname of the website IFrame is embedded in

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I get the hostname of the website Iframe is embeded to using jquery? for example this iframe

```
<iframe src="xyz.com/123" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" width="640" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: does `window.parent.location` work for you? or you can also try `document.referrer;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like :

```
$("iframe").attr("src");
```

or if looking for parent URL

```
$(function(){
  var currentUrl = document.referrer;
  alert(currentUrl)
});
```

Comment: he's trying to get the url of the site where `iframe` is embedded.

Comment: you are right Sushil, also I would like to take the hostname of the website iframe is embedded to

Comment: Sorry @Imo , could you clarify by what you mean Hostname... I tihnk we have different definitions.

Comment: by hostname i meant xyz.com, but anyway I figured it out but now I get an error ncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin  from accessing a frame with origin Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: Yeah, I think what you are trying to do is known as cross site scripting, and is not allowed.

Comment: Get the referrer site url by `document.referrer` and the extract the domain using a RegEx match.